# Replace Multiple ID Values by Name Values in a dataframe's single column by iterating through

Tags: python, pandas, loops, replace, iteration

I have these two dataframes one for product file and one for category file (from CSVs):

Product File csv:

| prod_id | prod_name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Red T-Shirt | 501,502,999 |
| 345 | Blue Dress | 601,602 |

Category File csv:

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | Mens |
| 502 | T-Shirts |
| 601 | Women |
| 602 | Dresses |
| 999 | Sale |

Expected output as csv:

| prod_id | prod_name | category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Red T-Shirt | 501,502,999 | Mens,T-Shirts,Sale |
| 345 | Blue Dress | 601,602 | Women,Dresses |

Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df_products = pd.read_csv("products.csv", dtype="str")
df_categories = pd.read_csv("categories.csv", dtype="str")

cached_prod_id = df_products["prod_id"]
cached_prod_name = df_products["prod_name"]
cached_prod_category_id = df_products["category_id"]

cached_category_id = df_categories["category_id"]
cached_category_name = df_categories["category_name"]

inner_join = pd.merge(df_products,df_categories, on="category_id", how="category_name")

print(inner_join)

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\projects\python\catagories_builder.py", line 29, in <module>
    inner_join = pd.merge(df_products,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 106, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 699, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1096, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'category_id'
```

I believe this is obviously not the correct code or even the approach is incorrect; as I am still new and still learning python / pandas.
I may have a feeling that I need to iterate in the category_id column in product csv to get the values that are separated by commas THEN do a replace or something??!

I have explored index, map, split and replace functionality in pandas but unfortunately haven't worked it out.
I am sure this is simple thing and is there already an efficient approach to solve this problem, hopefully :)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

- Create a mapping series from `df_categories`
- `Split` and `explode` the `category_id` column
- Substitute the values in the exploded `catgeory_id` using the values from mapping series
- Group the column by index and aggregate the column using `join`

```
d = df_categories.astype(str).set_index('category_id')['category_name']

df_products['category_name'] = (
    df_products['category_id'].str.split(',')
    .explode().map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
)
```

---

```
>>> df_products

   prod_id    prod_name  category_id       category_name
0      123  Red T-Shirt  501,502,999  Mens,T-Shirts,Sale
1      345   Blue Dress      601,602       Women,Dresses
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham!! I quickly tried it and it seems to work ok!. However I still may have to do few tweaks to it as currently I get some category_ids concatenated to category names when using Real Data which I've got!! But thanks for this, really appreciate your solution and hopefully I will utilize it in my solution.

Comment: Just an update.. This is the problem I get when using it with real Data where mapping is coming up as incorrect and also concat of IDs with the name :(

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uZQbOKu
https://imgur.com/a/Eu34Trl

Comment: @TheMissingNTLDR I've edited the answer.

Comment: this is a beauty! Absolutely works like a charm! Bahut badia :) Thank you!!!

Comment: @TheMissingNTLDR Happy coding!